# Is there a difference between the <cors> tag in web.config and this httpProtocol with Custom Header?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, cors, web-config

Currently in an ASP.NET Core MVC application, I am adding the following `web.config` to a site:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <cors enabled="true">
            <add origin="*" />
        </cors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But I have received feedback that some clients are needing to replace my cors tag with the following:

```
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
```

I was wondering in what ways these are functionally different? They look to me like they would have the same result, but it doesn't seem that they do in practice.

Edit: I do wonder if the issue is that some of these servers are missing the IIS Cors Module.  Reading the [MSDN Documentation for the cors tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference#using-only--origin-host-rule) it seems to be equivalent to the second option as each is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplest cases the two approaches are equivalent, but they have completely different results in complex scenarios, especially when your web app is protected by Windows authentication.

`<cors>` as part of IIS CORS module allows you to configure in such cases, while if you choose custom response headers you are fully on your own.